# Clicking on "Applications" in the top-left corner opens a terminal

Tags: applications, pantheon-terminal, dconf

I've been playing around with dconf tools. I'm not sure what I've done but now when I try to click on Applications, a terminal opens. So far, clicking everywhere else works fine. Any ideas? Thanks!